# Estimate arc length of an ellipse; proving the inequality $\pi(a+b) \le L \le 2\pi \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Tags: inequality, analytic-geometry

By $\gamma(t) := \space(a\cos(t), b\sin(t))^T$ with $a,b > 0$ and $0 \le t \le 2\pi$ we define an ellipse.

Now I want to prove that the arc length is bound by $a$ and $b$ so that the following inequality hold:

$$\pi(a+b) \le L \le 2\pi \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

I tried using the definition and got:
 $$L := \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt$$
which is equal to:
$$a\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1-\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2}\cos^2(t)}dt$$
Since the integral can't be solved by integrating I tried generating the Taylor Series with $c := \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a}$:
$$1-\frac{1}{2}c^2\cos^2(t)-\frac{1}{8}c^4\cos^4(t)... $$
However I don't know how this will help me.. Has anyone an idea or another way to prove this inequality?

Kind Regards

EDIT:
Upper Bound:
 $$L = \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt \space \le \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2*1+b^2*1}dt = 2\pi \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
Lower Bound:
See Macavity for a full answer.

Comment: I just saw I comment that suggested using that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is concave. I have been already trying it, but I can't come up with an $x$ and an $y$ so that it works..

Comment: One direction can be done by noticing $sin^2 t \leq 1$, and similar for cos.

Comment: Yes, this proofs the upper bound.

Comment: AFAICT this has nothing whatsoever to do with neither elliptic curves (not to be confused with an ellipse) nor with functional analysis, so I removed the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So effectively we need to show
$$\pi (a+b) \leqslant L = 4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2t + b^2\cos^2t }  \: dt \leqslant 2\pi \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

**For the right inequality**, note for $x, y \geqslant  0$, we have $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leqslant x+y$, so $\sqrt{a^2\sin^2t + b^2\cos^2t } \leqslant a \sin t + b \cos t$, which integrated in $[0, \frac{\pi}2]$ gives the tighter bound $L \leqslant 4(a+b)$.
Using QM-AM, to conclude if needed.

**For the left inequality**, note from Cauchy-Schwarz we get:
$$(a^2\sin^2t + b^2\cos^2t)(\sin^2t + \cos^2t) \geqslant (a\sin^2t + b \cos^2t)^2$$
$$\implies L = 4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2t + b^2\cos^2t } \geqslant 4\int_0^\frac{\pi}2 (a \sin^2t + b \cos^2t) dt = \pi(a+b) $$

Comment: P.S. the upper bound can be made *much* tighter, $2 \pi $ can be replaced with $\pi/(2\sqrt2)$... using CS inequality again!

Comment: For the weaker upped bound all that is needed is to say that $\sin^2(t) \leq 1$ and $\cos^2(t) \leq 1$, combining these gives the easiest proof for the right inequality. Nice comment about making the bound tighter btw!

Comment: Is this really tighter? Because $a+b \ge \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: @Chiray - yes  because of QM-AM $\sqrt2 \;\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \geqslant (a+b)$.  In fact using CS we can show $4\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \leqslant L \leqslant \pi \sqrt2 \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ which makes the bounds better as $\pi \sqrt2  \approx 4.44$..

Comment: Seems like $\pi \sqrt{2} \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is a pretty good upper bound.

Comment: Ahh ok I see. Thank you!

Comment: @Macavity Sorry for asking again, but where did you replace $2\pi$ with $\pi/(2\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: I didn't replace, but one could prove $L \leqslant \pi/(2\sqrt2)\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, which is a tighter upper bound. You will need CS inequality for integrals in that case.

Comment: Is that $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ because I don't think that is true, that would make it even tighter than $\pi \sqrt{2} \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ which is the length of a circle..

Comment: ah never mind, I see what you meant